# Debugging Erlang Webmachine resource functions

Tags: debugging, erlang, webmachine

I'm trying to learn how to write Erlang Webmachine resources. One resource throws an error, but I can't tracking it down. The error message in the crash report does not provide enough information.

Is there a way to test these functions in the Erlang shell?

Most of the functions in the resource require request and context parameters. But I don't know how to simulate these parameters in the browser.

Example code below.

Thanks,

LRP

Example code:

I'm thinking specifically of functions like:

```
content_types_provided(RD, Ctx) ->
   Path = wrq:disp_path(RD),
   {[{webmachine_util:guess_mime(Path), generate_body}],
   RD, Ctx}.
```

But my current bug is in the init function.

This works...

Dispatch rule:

```
{["blip"], zzz_resource, []}.
```

Init:

```
init([]) -> {ok, undefined}.

to_html(ReqData, State) ->
    % {"<html><bodoy>Hello, new world</body></html>", ReqData, State}.
        {test:test(), ReqData, State}.
```

But this throws an error:

Dispatch:

```
{["static"], static_resource,[]}.
```

Init:

```
init(_) ->
   DocRoot =
       case init:get_argument(doc_root) of
          {ok, [[DR]]} -> DR;
           error -> "doc_root path error"
       end,
   {ok, #ctx{docroot=DocRoot}}.

=ERROR REPORT==== 4-Aug-2011::10:54:56 ===
webmachine error: path="/static"
{error,function_clause,
   [{filename,join,[[]]},
    {static_resource,resource_exists,2},
```

Comment: The error seems to occur in static_resource:resource_exists: what is its code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of layers to this answer depending on what you want to see and how deep down the rabbit hole you want to go.

---

Let's start with the easy stuff:

The error you are getting tells me that a call to `static_resource:resource_exists/2` resulted in a call to `filename:join/1` which failed because it was passed `[]` as its argument. That should help you track down the issue.

Recommended reading: [errors-and-exceptions](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-exceptions)

---

A crude way to track down errors in any language is just to add print statements at strategic loctations. In this case you can use `io:format/2` or `erlang:display/1` to display whatever you want to the console. For example:

```
...
erlang:display("I'm inside resource_exists!"),
StuffToJoin = ["foo", "bar"],
erlang:display(StuffToJoin),
filename:join(StuffToJoin),
...
```

Just reload the page you should see the value printed in the console (assuming the appropriate function was called as part of the reload).

---

If you want to manually test a resource (like in a unit test) you can do something like the following:

```
Headers = [{"Host", "mydomain.com"}, {"user-agent", "Firefox"}],
Context = [],
Path = "/static",
ReqData = wrq:create('GET', {1,1}, Path, mochiweb_headers:from_list(Headers)),
static_resource:resource_exists(ReqData, Context)
```

---

If you want a deep look at how to debug webmachine, you can read [this](http://webmachine.basho.com/debugging.html). You can get pretty far with the above, but doing a full trace can be helpful if you need to see the decision graph.

Comment: I think it would help if the OP could share the whole module code, it's hard to figure out what's wrong with only fragments of functions.

Comment: Hi @david, I'm making headway. You're the best. Thanks, LRP

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the various techniques David has suggested, you should also learn to use the [dbg](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dbg.html) module. It is incredibly powerful and lets you trace functions and modules in real time.

As an example, for your particular case, suppose you want to trace all the functions in static_resource module :

```
..
1> dbg:tracer().
{ok,}
2> dbg:p(all,[c]). 
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,25}]} 
3> dbg:tp({static_resource, '_', '_'}, []). 
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,5}]}
...
```

after which you will see a printout (includs all the function parameters in the function call) whenever static_resource module is invoked anywhere.

A full description of `dbg` is beyond the scope of this small answer space. I recommend O'rielly's [Erlang Programming](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596518189) book. Chaper 17 has a really awesome write up and tutorial on how to use it `dbg` and its various trace features.

Comment: I really appreciate this suggestion, Arun. I blown away by the incredible tool set surrounding Erlang. I will definitely put dbg in my quiver. I do have Erlang Programming, but haven't delved deeply enough into the later chapters. But I'm just now doing serious Erlang development, so it's time.  All the best, LRP